# ¿Como soluciono este problema en la creacion de una web en python?

Tags: python, ubuntu

Estoy tratando de crear un proyecto y siguiendo los pasos de un tutorial de la página: http://librosweb.es/libro/python/capitulo_13/python_bajo_apache.html, cuando llego al paso #4 que es Configurar el VirtualHost me dice esto:

```
 jp@JP:~/sitiopy/python-web$ sudo a2ensite python-web 

 ERROR: Site python-web does not exist!
```

No sé si ejecutar esta línea en la raíz o desde la carpeta donde estoy creando el programa. 
Este es el árbol de la app.

```
jp@JP:~/sitiopy$ tree
.
└── python-web
    ├── logs
    ├── mypythonapp
    │   └── controller.py
    └── public_html
```

4 directories, 1 file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a2ensite` no es un programa de python propiamente, es un acrónimo de Apache 2 ENable SIte, por lo que este comando es directamente manejado por apache,

En tu carpeta `/etc/apache2` existen una serie de archivos  y carpetas respecto a los virtual hosts, tienes que copiar el modelo `default` que vas a encontrar en `sites-available` y cambiarlo de acuerdo a tus necesidades, una vez hecho esto el comando a2ensite lo va a encontrar y pasarlo a `sites-enables` con lo que vas a poder empezar a tener tu virtual host corriendo.

Te dejo una [guía](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-virtual-hosts-de-apache-en-ubuntu-16-04-es) que tal vez te pueda ayudar un poco.